# SSRS - Need to hide column inside a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a requirement to hide a column, if no value exits in that column. But i have a grouping(Parent : Employee Number, Child: Category) in the report. In some of the group result may have value, but some of then does not have.

Example screen shot attached.

[image]

If you check the above image, second employee(Shiju) does not have Category. So for the second employee(Shiju) - need to hide Category column.

I tried with "Column Visibility" option and Column Groups > select Column > write expression in "Hidden" property. Following is the expr.

```
=iif(CountDistinct(Fields!Cat.Value) = 0,True,False)
```

These two options did not work.

Please give any solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update your question to include the expressions you've tried

Comment: Have you tried under visability to use an expression like : =IIF(isnothing(Fields!TestType.Value),True,False)

Comment: i gave aggregate function, otherwise it will take only first value.

Comment: I think this is not normal scenario. Please let me know any more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is almost correct, you just need to format the 0 else it will treat it as nothing:

```
=IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!cat.Value)=cint(0),true,false)
```

The other thing to check is that the field is actually null or nothing rather than blank strings or spaces.